# Numbers To Words in Python

Tags: python

I want write a program that accepts an integer between 1 and 9999 (inclusive) and prints the value in words. For example, if the user enters:

> 3421

then the program should print:

```
three thousand four hundred twenty one
```

My code is below, but it doesn't work.

```
num=int(input('please enter an integer between 1 and 9999: '))

def int_to_en(num):
    d = { 0 : 'zero', 1 : 'one', 2 : 'two', 3 : 'three', 4 : 'four', 5 : 'five', \
          6 : 'six', 7 : 'seven', 8 : 'eight', 9 : 'nine', 10 : 'ten', \
          11 : 'eleven', 12 : 'twelve', 13 : 'thirteen', 14 : 'fourteen', \
          15 : 'fifteen', 16 : 'sixteen', 17 : 'seventeen', 18 : 'eighteen', \
          19 : 'ninteen', 20 : 'twenty', \
          30 : 'thirty', 40 : 'fourth', 50 : 'fifty', 60 : 'sixty', \
          70 : 'seventy', 80 : 'eighty', 90 : 'ninty' }
    k = 1000
    m = k * 1000

    if (num < 20):
        print(d[num])

    if (num < 100):
        if num % 10 == 0:
            print(d[num])
        else:
            print(d[num // 10 * 10] + '' + d[num % 10])

    if (num < k):
        if num % 100 == 0:
            print(d[num // 100] + ' hundred')
        else:
            print(d[num // 100] + ' hundred ' + int_to_en(num % 100))

    if (num < m):
        if num % k == 0:
            print(int_to_en(num // k) + ' thousand')
        else:
            print(int_to_en(num // k) + ' thousand, ' + int_to_en(num % k))
```

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Comment: I think the code formatting got messed up between your original post (no formatting at all) and @CactusWoman's edit. Are these ``if`` really inside the function?

Comment: There is no initial call for `int_to_en`

Comment: You're never returning anything, so you can't use recursion.

Comment: Actually, he *can* use recursion.  The program prints successive values instead of passing the translations back up the line.

Comment: @CactusWoman You can run it in your system. That's had no error but no output!?

Comment: As others pointed out, it has no errors and no output because you never call the function from your main program.

Comment: Can any body edit my code, I don't know, that is true of false. I need write a program for print a word from my integer between 1 and 9999 as upper structure and no other structure!

Comment: @Prune Can you edit it for call or work without function?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.  When you clarify your problem statement, we need you to put the extra information into the main body of the question -- not in a comment below.

Answer (score 2):

I created such a function before.  It's not perfect, but it works pretty well:

```
def word_form(number):
    """word_form(number) -> string

    Returns the word form of the number.
    >>> word_form(32)
    'thirty-two'
    >>> word_form(123)
    'one hundred twenty-three'
    The highest number it is capable of converting is:
        999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999"""

    ones = ("", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine")
    tens = ("", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety")
    teens = ("ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen")
    levels = ("", "thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion", "quadrillion", "quintillion", "sextillion", "septillion", "octillion", "nonillion")

    word = ""
    #number will now be the reverse of the string form of itself.
    num = reversed(str(number))
    number = ""
    for x in num:
        number += x
    del num
    if len(number) % 3 == 1: number += "0"
    x = 0
    for digit in number:
        if x % 3 == 0:
            word = levels[x / 3] + ", " + word
            n = int(digit)
        elif x % 3 == 1:
            if digit == "1":
                num = teens[n]
            else:
                num = tens[int(digit)]
                if n:
                    if num:
                        num += "-" + ones[n]
                    else:
                        num = ones[n]
            word = num + " " + word
        elif x % 3 == 2:
            if digit != "0":
                word = ones[int(digit)] + " hundred " + word
        x += 1
    return word.strip(", ")
```

Usage example:

```
word_form(1)
>>> 'one'

word_form(999)
>>> 'nine hundred ninety-nine'
```

Comment: thanks a lot but I just write with this structure, that I wrote (without del, str and ...). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The return value for `int_to_en` is None, that will fail the concatenation in your code, try to return `String` instead and concatenate the result then.

```
num=int(input('please enter an integer between 1 and 9999: '))

def int_to_en(num):
    d = { 0 : 'zero', 1 : 'one', 2 : 'two', 3 : 'three', 4 : 'four', 5 : 'five', \
          6 : 'six', 7 : 'seven', 8 : 'eight', 9 : 'nine', 10 : 'ten', \
          11 : 'eleven', 12 : 'twelve', 13 : 'thirteen', 14 : 'fourteen', \
          15 : 'fifteen', 16 : 'sixteen', 17 : 'seventeen', 18 : 'eighteen', \
          19 : 'ninteen', 20 : 'twenty', \
          30 : 'thirty', 40 : 'fourth', 50 : 'fifty', 60 : 'sixty', \
          70 : 'seventy', 80 : 'eighty', 90 : 'ninty' }
    k = 1000
    m = k * 1000

    if (num < 20):
        return d[num]

    if (num < 100):
        if num % 10 == 0:
            return d[num]
        else:
            return d[num // 10 * 10] + ' ' + d[num % 10]

    if (num < k):
        if num % 100 == 0:
            return d[num // 100] + ' hundred'
        else:
            return d[num // 100] + ' hundred ' + int_to_en(num % 100)
    if (num < m):
        if num % k == 0:
            return int_to_en(num // k) + ' thousand'
        else:
            return int_to_en(num // k) + ' thousand, ' + int_to_en(num % k)

print int_to_en(num)
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I use for example 55, output is 55 times fiftyfive! So I need only one fiftyfive! I think I need break between if, right?

Comment: Yes, you need to add a missing space. Take a look at the corrected code above.

Answer (score 0):

Once you bother to call the function, the next problem you hit is that your **if** statements are not exclusive.  For instance, with an input of only **5** ... 
    You see that 5 < 20.
    You print "five".
    You go to the next if statement.  Sure enough, 5 < 100.
    You process the number as larger ... and go into an infinite recursion.

You have to make sure that you execute only *one* of those **if** statements.  For all but the first, use **elif** instead of **if**.

---

To get past your **None** problem, you can appropriately change your **print** statements to **return** statements.  Don't print anything until you get back to the main program; the other calls simply append the results as you figure them out, and the main program gets the whole string to print at once.

---

To save yourself a lot of time, please learn [basic debugging](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I corrected but till 99 write for example nintynine and in next line None! and when I write more than 99, show me like bellow error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/iSam/Desktop/number_to_word.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(int_to_en(num), end = "")
  File "/Users/iSam/Desktop/number_to_word.py", line 23, in int_to_en
    print(d[num//100]+' hundred '+int_to_en(num%100))
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly

Comment: This is exactly the problem that others have pointed out: you return **None** from your function.  When you return from a recursive call and try to concatenate the **None** to "hundred", you get an error.

Comment: Please make the changes we've suggested.  If you have a new problem after that and cannot solve it, please post a new question.  We've already fixed three problems in this one; StackOverflow is supposed to be one problem per posting.

Comment: Thanks, but I just use print and not return.